# Dealing with APIs in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I'm trying to optimize a lil project i was doing (Using .Net Core and React)  and i came across something i don't quite understand.

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGames()
    {  
            return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id select m;
    }
    [HttpPost("{Select}")]
    [Route("GetGamesPerSelect")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesPerSelect(string Select)
    {
        if (Select == null)
        {
            GetGames();
        }
        return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id & m.G_Genre == (Select) select m;
    }

    [HttpPost("{SearchString}")]
    [Route("GetGamesPerString")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesPerString(string SearchString)
    {

        if (SearchString == null)
        {
            GetGames();
        }
        return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id & m.G_Title.Contains(SearchString) select m;
    }
```

This was the backend controller and i got an api (GetGames) defined, that returns an IEnumerable type containing all games, but when i try to use it in other APIs (dealing with it like a normatl function), it just doesn't seem to work, which I'm very curious to understand the reason behind that.

P.S : implementing them like this totally works:

```
        [HttpPost("{Select}")]
    [Route("GetGamesPerSelect")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesPerSelect(string Select)
    {
        if (Select == null)
        {
            return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id select m;
        }
        return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id & m.G_Genre == (Select) select m;
    }
    [HttpPost("{SearchString}")]
    [Route("GetGamesPerString")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesPerString(string SearchString)
    {
        if (SearchString == null)
        {
            return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id select m;
        }
        return from m in _context.Games join n in _context.UserGame on m.G_Id equals n.GL_ID where n.USR_ID == User_id.user_id & m.G_Title.Contains(SearchString) select m;
    }
```

I've been trying to goolge it for the last 40 mins but i guess i'm having a problem picking the right words, since i'm getting weird results, that has nothing to do with what i'm looking for.

(i'm a junior devolper //been working less than 2 months in webdesign// so i'd really appreciate all the details you could give !)

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: When you say 'it just doesn't seem to work' what happens ? Can you include the code that you were using to call it ?

Comment: My problem is when i call "GetGamesPerString()" using a fetch post for example since in the first code i've said that the function "GetGames()" should be called if string == null but while debugging i can see that the "GetGames()" function isn't being called at all.
yet as in the second code, just getting all the games from the data base (same way used in "GetGames()") seems to work just fine.

Comment: So in your first code when calling GetGamesPerString, what's the value of SearchString ?  If you put a breakpoint on the if statement, does that get hit ?

Comment: no it doesn't and that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never mixed `Route` and `HttpXXX` attributes on a method. Also it's quite uncommon to declare a POST request that doesn't alter or creates something.

So I would change the methods to something like this:

```
[HttpGet("GetGamesPerSelect/{select}")]
public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesPerSelect(string select)
{
}

[HttpGet("GetGamesPerString/{searchString}")]
public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesPerString(string searchString)
{
}
```

Comment: True, but one could consider to put a class global RouteAttribute on the class and then specify method specific HttpXxxAttributes on the individual methods. Like specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#combining-routes)

Comment: @JHBonarius: Yes, you're right and I do the same myself. But these are different levels (class and method), but on the same level you shouldn't use both.